# Android: Smooth fade animation

Tags: android

I'm attempting to fade between two background images on my Droid, but the animation seems to get 5fps if not less. Is there any method I can use other than fading in\out a couple image views that would be smoother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, but if you want to change from one screen to the other within the same app you should use the ViewFlipper.

[View Flipper on Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)

This will allow to smoothly change from one screen to the other (much like the iPhone way).

If it is about the actual Android background i can't help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your background to be defined by a [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html). Used it to develop a nice splash screen that fades in and didn't have any issues.